# How to truncate carriage return when pasting into Python

Tags: python, copy, clipboard, paste, carriage-return

I created a function that will copy to the system clipboard. However, when I paste the value from the clipboard, it automatically does a carriage return. This drastically affects calculations in my program.

Note: Cannot Use Pyperclip or any other installation. I can only use what's included in Python IDLE 3.8 for this

I've tried using the strip() method with the clipboard_answer variable. It still returns to the next line

```
def copy(solution_answer): 
    clipboard_answer = str(solution_answer)
    command = 'echo ' + clipboard_answer.strip() + '| clip' # Creates command variable, then passes it to the os.system function as an argument. CMD opens and applys echo (number calculated) | clip and runs the clipboard function
    os.system(command)
    print("\n\n\n\n",solution_answer, "has been copied to your clipboard") # Used only for confirmation to ensure copy function runs
```

Pretend the "|" icon is the cursor

I have a solution that was copied to my clipboard, i.e. 25

When I CTRL+V in the program I expect it to do this

25 |

But in actuality, the cursor is like this

25

|

Comment: What commandline are you using?

Comment: Using Python IDLE 3.8

Comment: Windows command line

Comment: The `echo` adds a newline at the end per default. You can turn that off with `-n` I think.

Comment: Use `printf`; `-n` is a `bash` extension to `echo`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey command = 'echo -n ' + clipboard_answer.strip() + '' + '| clip'

I tried that but did not do anything but copy the -n to my clipboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `os.system`. Use `subprocess`, and you can feed the string directly to the standard input of `clip` without invoking a shell pipeline.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

Popen(["clip"], stdin=PIPE).communicate(bytes(solution_answer))
```

Comment: Is Popen a program that requires installation?

I should've clarified this but I need to be able to do this without any software installations.

Comment: No, it's a class imported from the `subprocess` module in the standard library.

Comment: TypeError: cannot convert 'float' object to bytes

Comment: OK, then you'll have to encode it explicitly. `str(solution_answer).encode()` If you don't want UTF-8, pass the name of the appropriate encoding to `encode`.

Comment: You are a lifesaver, thank you that worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyperclip

pyperclip.copy(solution)
```

This should do the trick.

EDIT: The tkinter solution again since pyperclip is no option for OP.

```
from tkinter import Tk

r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
r.clipboard_clear()
r.clipboard_append("hello world")
r.update()
```

Comment: Wish I could, project I'm doing prohibits pyperclip

Comment: @KatJohnson-tapp you should specify that.. ps.: Updated the Answer to include a non `pyperclip` solution

Comment: This didn't do anything unfortunately, it just crashed the IDLE.